# Can a spring boot application have multiple Failure Analyzers?

Tags: spring-boot

Can a spring boot application support multiple custom Failure Analyzers? If Yes how is it configured? in spring.factories you can have only one property as below

org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=xxxxxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your multiple custom Failure Analyzers using comma separator like below

```
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=com.x.x.CustomFailureAnalyzer1, com.x.x.CustomFailureAnalyzer1
```